# Is there anyway group the errors of multiple form validations in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-validation

In the given scenario

```
request()->validate([
    'type' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required'
]);

and Again

request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required
]);
```

Is it possible to get some sort of centralized or complied error that encompasses both the validations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should use Validator facade to handle this kind of cases.
for ex.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->only('type', 'category), [
    'type' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required'
]);

$validator2 = Validator::make($request->only('name', 'gender'), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails() || $validator2->fails()) {
    // return merge $validator->errors() and $validator2->errors();
}
```